# Automatically apply a banner to the top of all html files

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm trying to apply a banner to the top of all html files to notify users that the pages will expire soon. My first idea was to use auto_prepend_file in htaccess but it keeps throwing a 500 internal server error. In my .htaccess file I put php_value auto_prepend_file ".banner.php" where banner.php was just a file in the same directory as the htaccess file. I'm not sure why it doesn't work

My next idea was to use the .htaccess file to detect urls ending in .html and then send the user to another page that would basically just be a frame around the current page but this sounds fairly silly.

Any ideas on how I would accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer would be to send everyone to a page called banner.php and have that page fetch the content of the html file they were trying to access. Then echo the content of that html page the user is trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be possible to use a layout master page (_layout.html) and reference the layout file in each html page? Source code for an example.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114458/Master-Pages-using-HTML-and-JavaScript